# Install Ubuntu 12.04 in UEFI mode on a HP Pavilion dv6-6c40ca

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, hp-pavilion, uefi

**## I never did get this to work and eventually gave away the laptop. ##**

Marked for deletion? Or is it still useful to people?

I have recently (as of July 2012) bought a HP Pavilion dv6-6c40ca laptop. It came pre-installed with Windows 7 on an MBR. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on it on a GPT partition in what I *think* is BIOS emulation mode. I made a BIOS-Grub partition so the install didn't fail. That is what it is for .. right? Now I want to upgrade to UEFI mode.

How would I Install Ubuntu 12.04 in UEFI mode on a HP Pavilion dv6-6c40ca.

Or is it impossible? My laptop, despite its new age may not be UEFI 2.0+ capable. If it isn't how can I install a software UEFI (i.e. a DUET such as the one by tianocore). Or is this too impossible?

A link to my laptop's specs is: http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c03137924&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&cc=ca&dlc=en&lang=en&lc=en&product=5218530

My laptop should have a UEFI given this link from HP http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c01442956#N218. And from the link I draw a quote: *That means most notebooks distributed with Windows Vista, and **all notebooks distributed with Windows 7**, have the UEFI environment.* My laptop had Windows 7 Home Premium pre-installed.

---

OK. Following the comments so far --

*NOTE: I am trying to do this on an external drive so I can see if it works.*

1. I have partitioned the drive using GParted as a **GPT drive**.
2. Created a **200MB partition at the beginning of the drive with a FAT32** file system.
3. Given the 200MB partition a **label of "EFI"**.
4. Set the **boot flag** on the 200MB partition.

What should a do next to install Ubuntu 12.04?

Given the link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting#Selecting_the_.28U.29EFI_Graphic_Protocol

In my first read through (just to see if I will understand everything before I start) I get to step **2.3 Install GRUB2 in (U)EFI systems**

The first line is *Boot into Linux (any live ISO) preferably in UEFI mode.* Um .. **how do you tell what mode your live CD is in?!** And how do you change it if the mode is wrong?

Comment: It's possible. Here is described how: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31199/what-should-i-do-before-dual-booting-windows-7-and-debian-on-efi/40775#40775

Comment: The article is an interesting read .. but it is a little high level for me. Do you think you could provide a step by step (with backup/restore of my data) version?

Answer (score 2):

Did you solve your problem. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 in UEFI mode on my ThinkPad T420. I will share some important points. Hope it is helpful.

1. Set the BIOS to UEFI only mode.
2. After created FAT32 partition on GPT drive and set the boot flag on it, you just need to create other partition you need, like /, /var.
3. Actually, it is done. Just follow the installation guide and then reboot system. You would be able to boot system in UEFI mode.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I've never installed dual OS in UEFI. My answer focuses on single OS, only Linux. If you want to install dual OS in UEFI mode, I'm afraid I can't help.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is possible to convert an existing MSDOS (MBR) install of Windows
   to GPT. Follow this instruction [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14286.converting-windows-bios-installation-to-uefi.aspx) It is even possible to determine if Windows installer is running UEFI mode BEFORE actual install. See [Windows Installer Running UEFI mode?](https://superuser.com/questions/464760/how-to-tell-if-windows-7-installer-boot-in-efi-or-bios)
2. It should then be the simple case of leaving UEFI on and install
           Ubuntu to unallocated space.

The only criteria being is make sure you are using a  Ubuntu 64bit .iso and are familiar with and understand your firmware settings.  To determine if your system is Secure Boot capable try running msinfo32 after installing Windows using UEFI. (Try the conversion process linked to above)  Secure Boot is just another firmware setting!.  Secure Boot needs UEFI >= 2.2. Windows 8 demands UEFI >= 2.3.1 to use Secure Boot but installs to older versions of U/EFI without Secure Boot.

Using `lsefisystab` from grub command prompt will confirm your U/EFI version being used and if system is secure boot capable when booting Ubuntu installation media using U/EFI mode. i.e.: Boot Ubuntu installation media with U/EFI on and press <kbd>C</kbd> when you see black grub screen to get grub command line to enter `lsefisystab` to get U/EFI version info. (see below)

The only way to upgrade your UEFI version that i am aware of being possible is to wait for updates to firmware from vendor.  ie: Flash to latest firmware update from vendor.

To identify Ubuntu is booting U/EFI mode is brilliantly illustrated here ([Ubuntu Documentation UEFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI))

> Identifying if the computer boots the Ubuntu DVD in EFI mode

Warning: even if your PC boots the DVD in EFI mode, it might boot the HDD in Legacy mode (and the contrary).

When booting on a 64-bit Ubuntu disk:

- If the BIOS is set up to boot the CD in EFI mode, then you will see the screen below:

[image: Grub U/EFI mode]

- If the BIOS is NOT set up to boot the CD in EFI mode, or if the disk is not 64-bit, then you will see the screen below:

[image: Grub BIOS/Legacy mode]

It may be that trying to run installer U/EFI mode will not run (switch U/EFI off if it does not run) or the fallback installer runs using BIOS/Legacy settings.
This will mean you could use boot-repair to fix the boot loaders. See [Ubuntu Documentation UEFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Converting_Ubuntu_into_EFI_or_Legacy_mode)

This has been deliberately simplified synopsis even easier than 1,2,3...  Please comment if and when you get stuck.

I have found these pages at [rodsbooks](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/index.html) absolutely invaluable for starting to get any understanding of all things U/EFI.