# Can you install Windows 7 after installing Windows 8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, multi-boot

I installed Windows 8 and it works great, but I need to use some software that isn't available on Windows 8 (Windows DVD Maker). Is it possible to install Windows 7 again in a dual boot scenario and if so, how would one go about doing this?

Thanks ahead

Comment: Windows has been pretty good about backwards compatibility.  Would it work to just run it in compatibility mode (right-click the .exe, Properties, compatibility tab) or do you need a dual-boot for other reasons?

Comment: @BrianDaniels You can't even install Windows DVD Maker on Windows 8...

Comment: You might find it easier to install free or cheap alternatives to WDM than to downgrade your whole system just to get one program back.

Answer (score 0):

I've not done a Windows/Windows dual boot for a long time. I'm guessing that it hasn't got any easier especially now that Windows 8 wants UEFI instead of a BIOS. It used to take a utility to manage the boot partitions and boot sectors properly.

The alternative, if your PC is up to it, would be to run a virtual machine. I run VirtualBox generally for this kind of thing. Just fire up a VM with Windows 7 installed. Of course, there is the little issuette of licensing another copy of Windows. Not a problem if you are a Microsoft business partner or have a Technet or MSDN subscription.

Comment: Yeah I thought about using a virtual machine...

Answer (score 0):

Since you installed Win8 yourself, I don't know what sort of hardware you have. A new Win8 PC would be [**UEFI**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface)-based, [**Secure Boot**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Secure_boot) would be enabled and the hard disk would most likely be [**GPT**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) formatted. In any case, all you need to do is ensure **Secure Boot** is turned off if available, options like **Legacy BIOS** or **Compatibility Support Module (CSM)** are *not* enabled under UEFI settings (ignore if your PC lacks UEFI and has only BIOS), then boot from the Win7 DVD. The 64-bit WIn7 DVD [supports both BIOS and UEFI](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2011/05/31/installing-windows-7-on-uefi-based-computer.aspx), so as long as you boot using the appropriate mode it will install as usual on either system type. You can also [confirm](https://superuser.com/questions/464760/how-to-tell-if-windows-7-installer-boot-in-efi-or-bios) which mode the installer booted in. Finally, while there are any number of utilities to transfer Win7 Setup to USB for BIOS systems, a USB-based UEFI installation is [also possible](http://hodgin.ca/2012/10/02/creating-a-uefibios-windows-7-usb-and-installing-to-gpt-partitions/).

Note that you'll need to shrink the Win8 partition beforehand using **Disk Management** or 3<sup>rd</sup> party Windows partitioning software to free up space for Win7, and a defrag is recommended before shrinking for best results (or better still you can use [**GParted**](http://gparted.sourceforge.net) for this).

After Win7 is installed you'll need to boot from the Win8 DVD/USB and run **Startup Repair** or enter the [**BootRec**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392) **/FixMbr**, **/FixBoot** and **/RebuildBcd** parameters to restore the Win8 graphical bootloader and add a Win7 entry to it.