# Is there a way to know if the system you are on is BIOS or UEFI?

Tags: bios, uefi, thinkpad

Is there a way to guess from the running system if you have BIOS or UEFI? If so, then how ? I am running Debian as my main OS.

If not, if I go to BIOS or UEFI menu is there a way to check which way is functioning? This is on a Lenovo T-Series T-440 laptop.

Comment: Do you mean whether the system actually booted using BIOS or UEFI? Or what it's capable of doing?

Comment: Windows Solution: http://superuser.com/questions/464760/how-to-tell-if-windows-7-installer-boot-in-efi-or-bios

Comment: Linux Solution: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148356/how-to-know-if-im-booting-using-uefi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most Linux distributions, the simplest way to do this is to check for the presence of a directory called `/sys/firmware/efi`:

```
$ ls -F /sys/firmware
acpi/  efi/  memmap/
```

If it's present, as in this example, then you're booted in EFI mode. If it's absent, then you've *probably* booted in BIOS mode; however, there are ways to boot in EFI mode and to not have this directory. These methods typically involve rare configurations or passing boot options to the kernel that disable EFI support.

If you think one of these issues may be at play, you can examine the kernel ring buffer with `dmesg`, and search for lines that include the string `EFI` (or `efi`, for some lines):

```
$ dmesg | grep -i efi
[    0.000000] Command line: \vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-generic.efi.signed ro root=/dev/mapper/louiswu-trusty_crypt  quiet splash  initrd=\initrd.img-3.13.0-65-generic
[    0.000000] efi: EFI v2.31 by INSYDE Corp.
[    0.000000] efi:  ACPI=0x9cffe000  ACPI 2.0=0x9cffe014  SMBIOS=0x9cebef98 
[    0.000000] efi: mem00: type=3, attr=0xf, range=[0x0000000000000000-0x0000000000001000) (0MB)
[    0.000000] efi: mem01: type=2, attr=0xf, range=[0x0000000000001000-0x0000000000007000) (0MB)
...
[    0.950130] efifb: probing for efifb
[    0.951549] efifb: framebuffer at 0xa0000000, mapped to 0xffffc90010f00000, using 8100k, total 8100k
[    0.951551] efifb: mode is 1920x1080x32, linelength=7680, pages=1
[    0.951552] efifb: scrolling: redraw
[    0.951554] efifb: Truecolor: size=8:8:8:8, shift=24:16:8:0
[    0.963414] fb0: EFI VGA frame buffer device
[    1.033729] EFI Variables Facility v0.08 2004-May-17
[    1.145930] fb: conflicting fb hw usage inteldrmfb vs EFI VGA - removing generic driver
[    1.911331] tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 2394.456 MHz
```

This can be a little trickier to parse because you might find a few "EFI" lines even on a BIOS-based computer, and especially if the firmware is actually an EFI but uses CSM/legacy support to boot in BIOS mode. An EFI-mode boot will have many lines similar to those shown above, though, and in particular a long series of `efi: mem##` lines. (I trimmed it to just two such lines in this example for brevity.)

One problem with this approach is that the kernel ring buffer is of limited size, and as more messages are logged to it, old ones may disappear. Thus, if the computer has been up for a long time, all the relevant EFI messages may be missing.

One more point: Your question is a little bit ambiguous -- it's not quite clear about whether you want to discover in what mode you're *currently running* or what your hardware is *capable of doing.* I've assumed the former question in this answer up to now. If you want to learn your hardware's capabilities, then the preceding tests may help; if you've booted in EFI mode, then you almost certainly have EFI firmware. (It's possible to use DUET or Clover to run an EFI atop an old-style BIOS, but these are pretty rare configurations that take significant effort to set up, so you'd probably know if you'd done that, at least on a computer that you manage.) If you discover that you've booted in BIOS mode, though, you could still have an EFI. If you think this is the case, you'll just have to dig through your firmware setup utility's options for clues. Look in particular for anything with the terms "EFI," "UEFI," "CSM," or "legacy boot"; these terms all are usually indicators that the firmware is an EFI. The last two indicate that it provides a CSM to support BIOS-mode booting. Most EFIs provide a CSM, but a few (particularly low-powered machines like tablets) don't. The age of your computer may also be important. Most computers introduced in mid-2011 and later provide EFIs, as do a few sold before then. All Intel-based Macs use EFIs, too. The date test is not perfect, though; I bought an EFI-based machine in 2007 or thereabouts and a BIOS-based computer as recently as 2014, just as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not familiarized with Linux-based OS, but you can always go to the BIOS, and in the Advanced (if exists) or Security tab you can check that information: generally is a setting you can set its value to UEFI boot or Legacy support.