# Is there any test from the windows command line to prove whether a UEFI/BIOS booted as UEFI, or as Legacy?

Tags: windows, command-line, bios, uefi

Is there any test from the command line to prove whether a UEFI/BIOS booted as UEFI, or as Legacy?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/464760/how-to-tell-if-the-windows-installer-boots-in-efi-or-bios

Comment: In PowerShell, `$env:firmware_type` will return either "UEFI" or "Legacy"

Answer (score 0):

maybe https://itsfoss.com/check-uefi-or-bios/

there's a way from bcdedit, if it says winload.exe or if it says winload.efi

(and if one were in windows then msinfo32/system information, lists bios mode, as Legacy or UEFI)

(and if one were in linux, then, if `/sys/firmware/efi` exists means system uses UEFI. And that link mentions another method from linux too)

a great method is to look at `X:\Windows\panther\setupact.log` if off a DVD,  or if off a regular windows installation then  `C:\Windows\panther\setupact.log`` as mentioned in the similar question